# Order by nested select

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

I am using the following SELECT to fetch data from a database.

Is there a way to order the results by an item from the nested select?
I tried `ORDER BY B.ID` but that creates an error.

**My stored procedure:**

```
SELECT      (
                SELECT      B.ID,
                            B.FirstName,
                            B.LastName
                FROM        Users B
                WHERE       B.UserNum = A.UserNum
                FOR XML     PATH(''), ELEMENTS, TYPE
            )
FROM        User_SolutionRole A
WHERE       A.Solution = 'SPR'
FOR XML PATH('users'), ELEMENTS, TYPE, ROOT('ranks')
```

Comment: ORDER BY number of that column `ORDER BY 1`

Comment: Thanks, I get an error when trying this: Msg 305, Level 16, State 1, Procedure FetchUsersAll, Line 23
The XML data type cannot be compared or sorted, except when using the IS NULL operator.

Comment: Try `ORDER BY CAST(B.ID AS NVARCHAR(100))`

Comment: Nope: Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure FetchUsersAll, Line 23
The multi-part identifier "B.ID" could not be bound.

Comment: Then I get: Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure FetchUsersAll, Line 23
Invalid column name 'ID'.

Comment: @Mihai Don't recommend to order by the column number. What if the column list changes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we could apply the [`values()` method](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178030.aspx) to the main SELECT's only column to extract the `ID` values from it, we could use the results to sort the rows, like this:

```
<column_ref>.values('ID[1]', 'int') ASC
```

It is actually possible to achieve that. If you assigned the column the name `users` and, at the same time, replaced `PATH('users')` with `PATH('')`, like this:

```
SELECT      (
                SELECT      B.ID,
                            B.FirstName,
                            B.LastName
                FROM        Users B
                WHERE       B.UserNum = A.UserNum
                FOR XML     PATH(''), ELEMENTS, TYPE
            ) AS users
FROM        User_SolutionRole A
WHERE       A.Solution = 'SPR'
FOR XML     PATH(''), ELEMENTS, TYPE, ROOT('ranks')
;
```

you would get the same output but the column would now have a reference. That would be your first step towards the goal.

It would seem you'd only need to add an ORDER BY like this:

```
SELECT      (
                SELECT      B.ID,
                            B.FirstName,
                            B.LastName
                FROM        Users B
                WHERE       B.UserNum = A.UserNum
                FOR XML     PATH(''), ELEMENTS, TYPE
            ) AS users
FROM        User_SolutionRole A
WHERE       A.Solution = 'SPR'
ORDER BY    users.value('ID[1]', 'int') ASC
FOR XML     PATH(''), ELEMENTS, TYPE, ROOT('ranks')
;
```

That wouldn't work, however, not at this point, because the alias assigned in a SELECT clause can only be referenced by the same level ORDER BY clause *as is*, i.e. it cannot be part of an expression. And so the above would result in a compilation error.

The solution to that would be to assign the name *prior* to the main SELECT. There are basically two ways:

1. Using a derived table:

   ```
   SELECT      users
   FROM        (
                   SELECT      (
                                   SELECT      B.ID,
                                               B.FirstName,
                                               B.LastName
                                   FROM        Users B
                                   WHERE       B.UserNum = A.UserNum
                                   FOR XML     PATH(''), ELEMENTS, TYPE
                               ) AS users
                   FROM        User_SolutionRole A
                   WHERE       A.Solution = 'SPR'
               ) AS s
   ORDER BY    users.value('ID[1]', 'int') ASC
   FOR XML     PATH(''), ELEMENTS, TYPE, ROOT('ranks')
   ;
   ```

   The above uses a "normal" subselect but it would be no difference if you declared it as a [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) instead.
2. Using [`CROSS APPLY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156.aspx):

   ```
   SELECT      x.users
   FROM        User_SolutionRole A
   CROSS APPLY (
                   SELECT      B.ID,
                               B.FirstName,
                               B.LastName
                   FROM        Users B
                   WHERE       B.UserNum = A.UserNum
                   FOR XML     PATH(''), ELEMENTS, TYPE
               ) AS x (users)
   WHERE       A.Solution = 'SPR'
   ORDER BY    x.users.value('ID[1]', 'int') ASC
   FOR XML     PATH(''), ELEMENTS, TYPE, ROOT('ranks')
   ;
   ```

My personal preference would be the [CROSS APPLY technique](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9f9fd/10) as looking simpler and (to me) clearer, but the [former method](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9f9fd/11) would work equally well.

Comment: This is actually really good - I'll go with the cross apply. Thanks a lot for the detailed response !